# Java Simple Excercise

Tags: java

I am stuck into a Java excercise, so i would appreciate your help.

Here is the given excercise:

```
Public class FindVariables{
                Public static int x=7;
                Public int y=3;
}
FindVariables a=new FindVariables ();
FindVariables b= new FindVariables ();
a.x=1;
a.y=5;
b.x=2;
b.y=6;
System.out.println(“a.x=”+a.x);
System.out.println(“a.y=”+a.y);
System.out.println(“b.x=”+b.x);
System.out.println(“b.x=”+b.y);
```

Given output is:

```
a.x=2
a.y=5
b.x=2
b.y=6
```

Can you tell me why "a.x" gives the output of "2"?
How is this being calculated?

Comment: I don't think we should tell you, cause I guess it's your homework ^^. Hint : what is affecting "2" in your snippet of code ? How is that related with a.x ?

Comment: That's your output? My output is `FindVariables.java:1: class, interface, or enum expected [...] 14 errors` ;)

Comment: @Carsten Because he didn't include the `main` method in his question of course :P

Comment: @Doorknob One more mystery solved. :) Also, JonathanSmith, be careful, Java is case-sensitive. `public` is fine, `Public` is not.

Comment: That's some fancy quotes.

Comment: by the way I would advise using some pimped out IDE like Eclipse, it would give you warning at compile time that you are changing static field on an instance. More transparent way would be to call FindVariables.x = 1 instead of a.x = 1, but I get that it is an exercise

Answer (score 7):

Because `a` is `static`, which means that **all** `FindVariables` instances share **a single** `a`.

Therefore, when you do this:

```
b.x=2;
```

Then `a.x` will be `2` as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is becasuse x is static variable. There is no value for each instance only for the class.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is static. This means, that the variable is in the scope of the class, not the object.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `static` to variable,

> you announce that the variable is owned by the class

and not by any instance(Even though you may refer them using a reference variable).

Hence it would mean there exists only a single copy of the variable `a` across all objects that refer to it. Hence whether change a value using `a` or `b` you are editing the same copy.